# Google maps sample reading data

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am looking at the google map sample
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html

It seems to be reading the data from:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/data.json

Running through firefox with firebug, a var data.photos gets filled with the data.

Can someone explain how this is happening?
I must be missing something in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data object from data.json is available when it's included in the page.

data.json:

```
    var data = { "count": 10785236,
        "photos": [{".....
```